# Show that a certain set of points lies on a straight line

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving

Let $S$ be an infinite set of points in the plane. The distance between two points of $S$ is integral. Prove that $S$ is a subset of a straight line.

Here is my attempt: Suppose not, then for each line passing through two points $a$ and $b$, you can find a third point $c$ such that $c$ does not lie on the line. Hence $a,b,c$ form a triangle.  So pick a triangle $\triangle_s$ constructed like this of smallest area, then all other points lie outside of the triangle $\triangle_o$ whose midpoints of its edges are the vertices of $\triangle_s$. Then I'm stuck.

Comment: What does it mean that the distance between 2 points is integral?

Comment: I think that means the distance is a whole number in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes this is duplicate,I just checked